# Regex to match a few varieties of strings

Tags: php, regex

I'm wanting to use a regex to match this string, but have both "Cost" string be optional: Actual Cost Shipping Cost Item

```
$product = "Product ABC - Actual Shipping Item";
if(preg_match("/(Actual Cost Shipping Item)|(Actual Shipping Item)/i", $product)){
   echo "Setting Actual Shipping=1<br>";
   $actual_shipping=1;
}else{
   echo "Setting Actual Shipping=0<br>";
   $actual_shipping=0;
}
```

Thanks for your help, my brain is totally fried!  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use one of these:

```
/Actual (Cost )?Shipping Item/i
```

or:

```
/Actual( Cost)? Shipping Item/i
```

**Explanation:**

The `?` in this case means "Match zero or one of the thing immediately before it".

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php